# Logical Entailment

Tags: logic

Definition: "A set of sentences $\Delta$ logically entails a sentence $\varphi$ (written $\Delta \vDash \varphi$) if and only if every truth assignment that satisfies $\Delta$ also satisfies $\varphi$."

Question 1: If there is no truth assignment that satisfies a set of sentences $\Delta$, then what it means for $\varphi$?

Question 2: If a set of sentences $\Delta$ is empty,  then what it means for $\varphi$?

Answer (score 2):

1) Then for any interpretation $I$, the following conditional is true (by virtue of having a false antecedent): if $I$ satisfies $\Delta$ it satisfies $\varphi$. So $\Delta \vDash \varphi$. But that doesn't settle the value of $\varphi$ on any given interpretation. [Example: $p, \neg p \vDash q$, but that doesn't settle the value of $q$!]

2) If $\Delta$ is empty, then  $\Delta \vDash \varphi$ is equivalent to  $\vDash \varphi$. [Why? Any interpretation $I$ makes true the wffs in $\Delta$ -- that's the null task! -- so $\Delta \vDash \varphi$ comes to this: every interpretation makes $\varphi$ true, i.e. $\vDash \varphi$.]

Comment: Thank you.  
"... any interpretation makes φ true, i.e. ⊨φ."
How  an interpretation can makes φ true? My understanding from Stephen Kleene "Mathematical Logic" that ⊨φ is true iff is true for every interpretation.

Comment: The original version illustrated one of those occasions in English where "any" means every. But I've rephrased to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Dear Peter,
Thank you for your help. Finally, I understood Logical Entailment and have no problem with  p,¬p⊨q or Δ⊨φ  for every φ if Δ is empty set.
BUT, one thing steel bothers me. You wrote: "If Δ is empty, then Δ⊨φ is equivalent to ⊨φ."  I question this equivalence. According to Kleene: if ⊨φ than φ MUST BE tautology and in your example it is obviously that φ might be not a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: $\phi$ can be anything. If no truth assignment satisfies $\Delta$, then there are no truth assignments to check whether they satisfy $\phi$. Another way to say this is that an unsatisfiable $\Delta$ logically implies any $\phi$.

Question 2: $\phi$ is a logical truth, for example, "$p$ or not $p$". Every truth assignment satisfies the empty set of propositions, so that if $p$ is entailed by the empty set, than $p$ holds under any truth assignment. So $p$ will hold no matter truth values we assign to propositional variables. In fact for a connection with philosophy, the logician Alfred Tarski in the early 20th century defined the philosophical concept of a "logical truth" using this model-theoretical definition of a statement which is implied the empty set.

The answers to questions 1 and 2 are two extremes. If we make $\Delta$ very large, the set of truth assignments satisfying it will be as small as possible, and then the set of $\phi$ following from $\Delta$ will be as large as possible. Conversely if we make $\Delta$ very small, the set of truth assignments satisfying it will be very large, and then the set of $\phi$ following from $\Delta$ will be as small as possible, the set of logical truths. Hope that helps!