# The logical consequence of an empty set of premises.

Tags: self-learning, propositional-calculus

I am studying propositional logic by self-study, using a dutch book. I hope I am translating the terms to the correct English term. If my words are confusing, please please just let me know instead of editing my question (feel free to edit if I don't respond in a few weeks or so).

The logical consequence from an empty set of premises (a tautology) confuses me. My book explains the logical consequence $\Sigma \vDash \psi$ as such:

> If every interpretation that is a model for $\Sigma$, is also a model for $\psi$, then $\psi$ is the logical consequence of $\Sigma$.

If $\Sigma$ is an empty set, my reasoning is as follows: there exists no interpretation that makes $\Sigma$ true, there is no model for $\Sigma$, so there exist no models that are true for $\Sigma$ but not for $\psi$.

Unfortunately, my reasoning seems incorrect as my book explains (translation mine),

> **If $\Sigma = \emptyset$, then every interpretation is a model for $\Sigma$**,

which of course results in $\psi$ being a tautology.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) stays closer to what I understand:
($\psi$ is a logical consequence of $\Sigma$) if and only if there is no model in which all members of $\Sigma$ are true and $\psi$ is false. Or, in other words, the set of the interpretations that make all members of $\Sigma$ true is a subset of the set of the interpretations that make $\psi$ true.

> Why is every interpretation a model for an empty set of premises? A model is an interpretation that makes a premise true. Nothing is made true (or false) when the set is empty. What am I missing?

Some related material not answering my question (so that this question is not closed too quickly...): [Logical consequence (math SE)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362162/logical-entailment/363831) and [Visualing (...) entailment](http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/10/visualizing-satisfiability-validity-and-entailment).

Comment: "*If my words are confusing, please please just let me know instead of editing my question*" - Okay, but may I make a few changes to its title and layout? I'd remove the bit in parentheses, highlight your questions, and correct a few minor points of grammar :)

Comment: I've made the edit anyway. (I'm sorry.) I can put it back to its original form if you prefer :)

Comment: It has happened that questions were edited so much ("oh I am sure the question was meant to be this") that I could not recognize my own problem in it anymore... that's why I had put it there. You made it much nicer, but (there is one but...) the quote from the book was only the bold part. "which of course results(...)" was my summary of the rest.

Comment: Thank you. I've corrected the bit you pointed out :)

Answer (score 7):

See Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122384520) (2nd - 2001), page 23 :

> take the special case in which $\Sigma$ is the empty set $\emptyset$.
>
> Observe that it is *vacuously true* that any truth assignment satisfies every member of $\emptyset$. (How could this fail? Only if there was some unsatisfied member of $\emptyset$, which is absurd.) Hence we are left with : $\emptyset \vDash \psi$ iff every truth assignment (for the sentence symbols in $\psi$) satisfies $\psi$.
>
> In this case we say that $\psi$ is a *tautology* (written $\vDash \psi$).

As highlighted by Enderton, we have a case of [vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

The condition for an *interpretation* $I$ to be a model of $\Sigma$ is that all the sentences in $\Sigma$ must be satisfied by the interpretation $I$.

This is :

> for all $\sigma$, **if** $\sigma \in \Sigma$, **then** $I$ satisfy $\sigma$.

Thus, vacuous truth applies : there are **no** $\sigma \in \emptyset$.

---

What we are trying to convince ourselves is that : if $\emptyset \vDash \psi$, then $\psi$ is a *tautology*.

Consider again the definition of *logically implies*; there is a **double** conditional in place.

Saying that $\Sigma \vDash \psi$ means :

> for every interpretation $I$, [ **if** for every sentence $\sigma$, ( **if** $\sigma \in \Sigma$, **then** $I$ satisfy $\sigma$ ), **then** $I$ satisfy $\psi$ ].

In semi-formal way :

> > $\forall I [ \forall \sigma(\sigma \in \Sigma \rightarrow I \vDash \sigma) \rightarrow I \vDash \psi ]$.

When we put $\emptyset$ in place of $\Sigma$, the antecedent of the "inner" conditional is *false*; thus, by truth-table for $\rightarrow$, the conditional is *true* (and this says nothing about the truth-value of the *consequent* !).

In this way, the *antecedent* of the "outer" conditional is *true*. But we are *asserting* the fact that $\emptyset \vDash \psi$, i.e. that the "outer" conditional is *true*.

If it is true and if its antecedent is true, there is only one possibility left : the *consequent* is *true*.

I.e.

> > $I \vDash \psi$.

This hold for every $I$, and thus we can conclude that $\psi$ is a *tautology*.

---

*New addition*

We can try with another approach.

According to the definition of *logical consequence*, $\varphi \vdash \psi$ **iff** $\varphi \land \lnot \psi$ is *always* false.

Now, assuming that $\Gamma$ is a *finite* set of sentences, i.e. $\Gamma = \{ \gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_n \}$, we have that :

> $\Gamma \vdash \psi$ **iff** $\gamma_1 \land \ldots \land \gamma_n \land \lnot \psi$ is *always* false.

Thus, if $\Gamma = \emptyset$, the above condition boils down to :

> $\emptyset \vDash \psi$ **iff** $\lnot \psi$ is always false.

Obviously, $\lnot \psi$ is always false **iff** $\psi$ is a *tautology*.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I still don't get it though. Following the same reasoning one might say no truth assignment satisfies every member of $\Sigma$, since it is absurd there could be a satisfied member of $\Sigma$

Comment: Can I understand your last sentences as: "But we are certain that the outer conditional is true, since this is the definition. Since the antecedent is true, and the whole outer conditional, the consequent must also be true."

Comment: But really my main question is, why is every interpretation a model of the empty set of premises? It does not make the empty set of premises true. I tried to put emphasis on that in my question but maybe it got buried in too much surrounding material, sorry

Comment: @ChrisD - Ok; forget for the moment the *logical consequence* relation and consider only the "modelling" relation. We have that, for an int $I$, $I \vDash \Sigma$ when **all** the sentences in $\Sigma$ are satisfied by $I$; i.e.$I \vDash \Sigma$ iff $\forall \sigma(\sigma \in \Sigma \rightarrow sat_I(\sigma))$. If we agree on it, when $\Sigma = \emptyset$ $\sigma \in \Sigma$ is *false*. Thus the conditional is (vacuously) true and we have $I \vDash \emptyset$, for all $I$.

Comment: That is a very clear answer. But it steers just free of my problem :( sorry to be so annoying. I think I can, after your clear answer, narrow it further down to the definition of model. My book has: "an interpretation $I$ is a model of a formula $\psi$ when $I(\psi) = 1$". Would you say $\Sigma$ is true for every possible interpretation $I$ when $\Sigma = \emptyset$?

Comment: @ChrisD - we have still the same little "trick". If we start with *Definition n°1* : "an interpretation $I$ is a model of a formula $\psi$ **iff** $I(\psi)=1$", then what is the *Definition n°2* of :  $I \vDash \Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is a *set* of sentences ? Being consistent with *D_1*, we say : $I \vDash \Sigma$ **iff** $\forall \sigma (\sigma \in \Sigma \rightarrow I(\sigma)=1)$. Thus, what happens when $\Sigma = \emptyset$ ? Apply *D_2* and get : $\forall \sigma (\sigma \in \emptyset \rightarrow I(\sigma)=1)$; this is *vacuously true* and thus, due to the fact that ... 1/2

Comment: ... the RHS of the **bi-conditional** of *D_2* is *true*, also the LHS of it must be *true*. But the LHS of *D_2* (when $\Sigma = \emptyset$) amounts to : $I \vDash \emptyset$. 2/2

Comment: But the set of sentences $\Sigma$ as a whole never becomes true... or, (this took me a while to think out) to stay in your style of definitions, consider: $I \nvDash \Sigma$ iff $\exists\sigma(\sigma \in \Sigma \rightarrow I(\sigma) = 0)$ Here also the RHS is true for $\Sigma = \emptyset$ and thus the left side... (but I guess I am wrong :) )

Comment: @ChrisD - No, this does not work. **If** we agree with the *definition* : $I \vDash \Sigma$ iff $∀σ(σ∈Σ→I(σ)=1)$, we cannott define also its **negation**. The negation of $I \vDash \Sigma$, i.e. $I \nvDash \Sigma$ will be, by rules of logic : $\lnot ∀σ(σ∈Σ→I(σ)=1)$. This amount to : $\exists \sigma(\sigma \in \Sigma \land I(\sigma)=0)$ which has not the same "truth-conditions" of your formula.

Comment: ok maybe I should give up.... I understand all your explanations, (and the very nice latest addition!) but I cannot wrap my head around the idea that an empty set of premises is satisfied by any interpretation. And maybe, looking back, I do not know why your definition of logical consequence is not $I \vDash \Sigma$ iff $ \forall \sigma(\sigma \in \Sigma \wedge I(\sigma) = 1)$. But the system is already complaining we should not be chatting here... and I am probably using too much of your time. Thanks for all your efforts!

Comment: @ChrisD - simply because the condition ∀σ(σ∈Σ∧I(σ)=1) will never be satisfied. If a sentence $\tau$ is not in $\Sigma$, then $\tau ∈Σ∧I(\tau)=1$ is false. Thus, the universal formula ∀σ(σ∈Σ∧I(σ)=1) will never be true, unless $\Sigma$ includes **all** the sentences in the "universe". But if $\Sigma$ contains all the sentences, then it contains both $\tau$ and $\lnot \tau$ and thus the condition $I(\sigma)=1$ for all sentences will never be met. In conclusion, there are **no** $\Sigma$ such that $I \vDash \Sigma$.

Comment: of course! that is actually very obvious... sorry I had missed that. hm. Now what remains is why, when one evaluates an empty set of sentences, it results in true and not false or some form of 'undecided'. I guess what I miss is some kind of intuition for it all. It now feels like a debating trick, as if I have been lured into agreeing to something that is not quite right.

Comment: Alternatively you can show by monotonicity and the soundness theorem that $\emptyset \vdash G $ implies $\models G $